# Could not resolve com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.+

Tags: java, flutter

guys, when I tried to run my application on real device but I found that error after upgrading to 1.22.2:

> ```
>  Required by:
>      project :app > project :location
>   > Failed to list versions for com.google.android.gms:play-services-location.
>      > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-location/maven-metadata.xml.
>         > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-location/maven-metadata.xml'.
>            > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-location/maven-metadata.xml'.
>               > Read timed out
> ```
>
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

my android\app\build.gradle:

```
    def localProperties = new Properties()
    def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
    if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
        localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
            localProperties.load(reader)
        }
    }
    
    def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
    if (flutterRoot == null) {
        throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
    }
    
    def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
    if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
        flutterVersionCode = '1'
    }
    
    def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
    if (flutterVersionName == null) {
        flutterVersionName = '1.0'
    }
    
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
    apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"
    
    def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
    def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
    if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
        keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
    }
    
    android {
        compileSdkVersion 28
    
        lintOptions {
            disable 'InvalidPackage'
        }
    
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "io.bujupah.hestia"
            minSdkVersion 17
            targetSdkVersion 28
            versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
            versionName flutterVersionName
            multiDexEnabled true
        }
    
        signingConfigs {
            release {
                keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
                keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
                storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
                storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
            }
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            }
        }
    }
    
    flutter {
        source '../..'
    }
    
    dependencies {
        implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.1'
        testImplementation'junit:junit:4.12'
        testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:2.17.0'
        implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    }
```

my android\build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.2'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

and when I run flutter --version:

> Flutter 1.22.4 • channel stable •
> https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git Framework • revision 1aafb3a8b9
> (4 months ago) • 2020-11-13 09:59:28 -0800 Engine • revision
> 2c956a31c0 Tools • Dart 2.10.4

my location plugin:

```
 # flutter_map_marker_cluster: any
  flutter_polyline_points: ^0.2.4
  geolocator: ^6.1.1
  geocoding: ^1.0.5
  location: ^3.0.2
```

Comment: Did you manage to solve your issue?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

replacing `Jcenter()` with `mavenCentral()` works for me.

```
repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()  // Add this
    jcenter()    // remove this   
}
```

For REACT-NATIVE user: In your android folder, make this change in the `...\android\build.gradle` file.

Comment: some background info on why https://blog.gradle.org/jcenter-shutdown

Comment: does not fix my issues

Answer (score 17):

The solution is update

```
dependencies {
        com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.2
    }
```

to

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0'
    }
```

then update distributionUrl to be

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.5-all.zip
```

Comment: I can confirm this answer also works on my case with Flutter's Android build. Thanks, mate!

Comment: yeahhh...my old flutter project going live again, thanks

Answer (score 10):

**this below changes work for me**

```
//Project level build.gradle

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.+'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
    }
}


//App level build.gradle

configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        force 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'
    }
}
dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'//add this line 
}
```

Comment: worked by following above steps + this: `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.7.1-all.zip`

Comment: I think this best solution as it makes sure that you upgrade the Gradle to latest instead of downgrading

Answer (score 4):

for those of you who haven't solved the problem with AzizDev's solution, try this solution:

maybe some of your dependencies are outdated.. so, run this command in terminal to upgrade them and then run the project

```
flutter pub upgrade --major-versions
```

Comment: This should be the acepted answer as it solves the problem automatically and not by manually changing the gradle dependences.
Worked for me in two differents projects already.

Comment: Don't you have to update some code inside the project also?

Answer (score 2):

The Website is down for maintenance, look for jcenter() alternative or wait until they fix the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Go to your .pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/ go to your plugin and then go to android folder/ **change version of your com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.+ to specific version**. And then it will work perfect

**NOTE: Your .pub/cache folder path should be different in windows, Also you will need to unhide .pub-cache folder if it is hidden**

Comment: go to your plugin and then go to android. Which Plugin?

Comment: the plugin which is using play-services-location, in my case it was location plugin. This answer fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

Just check gradle versions in your flutter project, like this:

/android/build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.3'
    ...
}
```

/android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties:

```
...
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.5-all.zip
```

Answer (score 0):

If none of the answers worked for you, here's what I did to fix the issue :
(React Native)

- Completely delete node_modules
- yarn install or npm install again
- Clean your android build in yourProject/android/ (./gradlew clean)
- In Android studio click on sync your project files (elephant with blue arrow)
- Build again

That's it

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and fix it simply,play-services-location is used by location-acurracy plugin.There is two way to fix this issue

**First**
1-if you installed location-accuracy remove it with below command (ionic)

```
 ionic cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-request-location-accuracy && npm 
 uninstall @awesome-cordova-plugins/location-accuracy
```

2-add it again with below command (ionic)

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-request-location-accuracy -- 
variable PLAY_SERVICES_LOCATION_VERSION=16.0.0 && npm install @awesome- 
cordova-plugins/location-accuracy
```

**Third**

Fixed by android studio....

You can Check [This Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fytpPtcMxYU&ab_channel=ProgrammingwithAli) on the youtube For android studio fix

Hope it will Help :)