# Failed to list versions for com.google.android.gms:play-services-location

Tags: android, flutter, gradle, jcenter

Today I cannot run mu flutter application there is no changes since latest successful run

#### Error :

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.+.
     Required by:
         project :app > project :location
      > Failed to list versions for com.google.android.gms:play-services-location.
         > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-location/maven-metadata.xml.
            > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-location/maven-metadata.xml'.
               > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-location/maven-metadata.xml'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
      > Failed to list versions for com.google.android.gms:play-services-location.
         > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://storage.googleapis.com/download.flutter.io/com/google/android/gms/play-services-location/maven-metadata.xml.
            > Could not get resource 'https://storage.googleapis.com/download.flutter.io/com/google/android/gms/play-services-location/maven-metadata.xml'.
               > Could not GET 'https://storage.googleapis.com/download.flutter.io/com/google/android/gms/play-services-location/maven-metadata.xml'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
      > Failed to list versions for com.google.android.gms:play-services-location.
         > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-location/maven-metadata.xml.
            > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-location/maven-metadata.xml'.
               > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-location/maven-metadata.xml'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
      > Failed to list versions for com.google.android.gms:play-services-location.
         > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-location/maven-metadata.xml.
            > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-location/maven-metadata.xml'.
               > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-location/maven-metadata.xml'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
      > Failed to list versions for com.google.android.gms:play-services-location.
         > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-location/maven-metadata.xml.
            > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-location/maven-metadata.xml'.
               > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-location/maven-metadata.xml'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
      > Failed to list versions for com.google.android.gms:play-services-location.
         > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-location/maven-metadata.xml.
            > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-location/maven-metadata.xml'.
               > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-location/maven-metadata.xml'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
      > Failed to list versions for com.google.android.gms:play-services-location.
         > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-location/maven-metadata.xml.
            > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-location/maven-metadata.xml'.
               > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-location/maven-metadata.xml'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
      > Failed to list versions for com.google.android.gms:play-services-location.
         > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-location/maven-metadata.xml.
            > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-location/maven-metadata.xml'.
               > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-location/maven-metadata.xml'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
      > Failed to list versions for com.google.android.gms:play-services-location.
         > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-location/maven-metadata.xml.
            > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-location/maven-metadata.xml'.
               > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-location/maven-metadata.xml'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
      > Failed to list versions for com.google.android.gms:play-services-location.
         > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-location/maven-metadata.xml.
            > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-location/maven-metadata.xml'.
               > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-location/maven-metadata.xml'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
      > Failed to list versions for com.google.android.gms:play-services-location.
         > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-location/maven-metadata.xml.
            > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-location/maven-metadata.xml'.
               > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-location/maven-metadata.xml'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
      > Failed to list versions for com.google.android.gms:play-services-location.
         > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-location/maven-metadata.xml.
            > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-location/maven-metadata.xml'.
               > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-location/maven-metadata.xml'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
      > Failed to list versions for com.google.android.gms:play-services-location.
         > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-location/maven-metadata.xml.
            > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-location/maven-metadata.xml'.
               > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-location/maven-metadata.xml'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
      > Failed to list versions for com.google.android.gms:play-services-location.
         > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-location/maven-metadata.xml.
            > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-location/maven-metadata.xml'.
               > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-location/maven-metadata.xml'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
      > Failed to list versions for com.google.android.gms:play-services-location.
         > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-location/maven-metadata.xml.
            > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-location/maven-metadata.xml'.
               > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-location/maven-metadata.xml'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
      > Failed to list versions for com.google.android.gms:play-services-location.
         > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-location/maven-metadata.xml.
            > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-location/maven-metadata.xml'.
               > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-location/maven-metadata.xml'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
      > Failed to list versions for com.google.android.gms:play-services-location.
         > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-location/maven-metadata.xml.
            > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-location/maven-metadata.xml'.
               > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-location/maven-metadata.xml'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
      > Failed to list versions for com.google.android.gms:play-services-location.
         > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-location/maven-metadata.xml.
            > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-location/maven-metadata.xml'.
               > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-location/maven-metadata.xml'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
      > Failed to list versions for com.google.android.gms:play-services-location.
         > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-location/maven-metadata.xml.
            > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-location/maven-metadata.xml'.
               > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-location/maven-metadata.xml'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 2s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: Look this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/68146145/2554730 and this link https://blog.gradle.org/jcenter-shutdown

Answer (score 0):

Some of your dependencies may be outdated upon running your Flutter app. There are some solutions like the mentioned in the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68146145/8342742) which actually work on some use cases. This is a manual method of changing gradle dependencies. If this doesn't work, try to [update your dependencies automatically](https://docs.flutter.dev/release/upgrade#upgrading-packages) by running this in your terminal:

`flutter pub upgrade --major-versions`

You can also visit the [blog](https://blog.gradle.org/jcenter-shutdown) for more information on the impact of shutting down JCenter.