# Flutter Android Build Error com.google.android.gms:play-services-location

Tags: android, flutter

I have a problem as below. App works for ios but not for android.

> Could not get resource 'https://google.bintray.com/exoplayer/com/google/android/gms/play-services-location/maven-metadata.xml'.
> > Could not GET 'https://google.bintray.com/exoplayer/com/google/android/gms/play-services-location/maven-metadata.xml'. Received status code 502 from server: Bad Gateway

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUİLD FAILED in 1m 9s
The built failed likely due to AndroidX incompatibilities in a plugin. The tool is about to try using Jetfier to solve the incompatibility.
Building plugin admob_flutter...
env: sh\r: No such file or directory

Exception: The plugin admob_flutter could not be built due to the issue above.
Exited (sigterm)

Comment: you can check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66641552/could-not-resolve-com-google-android-gmsplay-services-location16  as issue is with android dependency

Comment: duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70319873/10659482