# Flutter : project don't run from another computer

Tags: flutter, gradle, build-error, bad-gateway

I build a project from windows computer. It's run perfectly and build perfectly in release mode. When I pull from another computer and try to run. It's show me build failed. And show this type of error.

```
Running "flutter pub get" in medimate-flutter-addition-features...         5.2s
The plugins `flutter_email_sender, geocoder` use a deprecated version of the Android embedding.
To avoid unexpected runtime failures, or future build failures, try to see if these plugins support the Android
V2 embedding. Otherwise, consider removing them since a future release of Flutter will remove these deprecated
APIs.
If you are plugin author, take a look at the docs for migrating the plugin to the V2 embedding:
https://flutter.dev/go/android-plugin-migration.
Launching lib/main.dart on M2010J19SI in debug mode...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.+.
     Required by:
         project :app > project :location
      > Failed to list versions for com.google.android.gms:play-services-location.
         > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://google.bintray.com/exoplayer/com/google/android/gms/play-services-location/maven-metadata.xml.
            > Could not get resource 'https://google.bintray.com/exoplayer/com/google/android/gms/play-services-location/maven-metadata.xml'.
               > Could not GET 'https://google.bintray.com/exoplayer/com/google/android/gms/play-services-location/maven-metadata.xml'. Received status code 502 from server: Bad Gateway

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 27m 38s
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                           1659.9s
[!] Gradle threw an error while downloading artifacts from the network. Retrying to download...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
```

But it's still run on previous computer. What's the error here ? Please Someone help me, I stack on here since 8/9 days.

Comment: Seems like duplicate of [Could not resolve com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.+](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66641552/10157127)

Comment: @YeasinSheikh My project works on previous computer

Comment: You can follow [Gradle threw an error while downloading artifacts from the network .. Exception:](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61986128/10157127)

Comment: @YeasinSheikh din't work. I tried before. I want to try this way - https://stackoverflow.com/a/70569128/12902996
Can you guide me to go this .pub-cache/hosted/ folder ?

Comment: check the Flutter version on both of your systems, and try to run Flutter clean command before trying to build on a new system

Comment: I think the problem is your Flutter version as it says that some of the plugins are using older version of Flutter. My guess is the system which builds the app successfully has the older version of flutter.

Comment: on new computer I use flutter version Management (FVM ) for 2.2.2.
And on old computer I using 2.2.2 directly