# How to solve Could not resolve com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:[15.0.0, 16.0.0). in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, location, google-play-services

Yesterday I run my code and didn't get any error but just so sudden... (I didn't edit my code) I got an error log like this

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:lintVitalRelease'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:[15.0.0, 16.0.0).
     Required by:
         project :app
      > Skipped due to earlier error

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 8s
```

I have tried by running it using another internet connection and still I get the same result. Is there a way to solve this (this error only happen when I run it using android and run so well in ios simulator)

Comment: Check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66641552/could-not-resolve-com-google-android-gmsplay-services-location16

Comment: @Yashraj Hi thankyou very much, I have found my solution by changing ```compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.6.1'``` into ```implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.6.1'```